# JQuery toggle visibility on mouseover of multiple images

Tags: jquery, css, hover, toggle, mouseover

Having problems with a simple jquery mouseover function.

I have a number of dynamically generated icons which when I hover will show a hidden div, and when I mouesout will hide the div.

```
 <div class='lister1'>
   <img src='"+path+stat1+"' />
   <img src='"+path+stat2+"' />
   <img src='"+path+stat3+"' />
   <img src='"+path+stat4+"' />
   <img src='"+path+stat5+"' />
   <img src='"+path+stat6+"' />
 </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.hover_pop').hide();

$(document).on('hover','.lister1 img', function(){
$('.hover_pop').show(), function(){
    $('.hover_pop').hide();
}
});
```

This will show the div but unfortunately will not hide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.8 using `hover` event with `on` method is deprecated, you can code:

```
$(document).on({
   mouseenter: function() {
       $('.hover_pop').show()
   },
   mouseleave: function() {
       $('.hover_pop').hide()
   } 
}, '.lister1 img');
```

Comment: Great - Thanks for your input. This is working fine for me now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('hover','.lister1 img', function(){
$('.hover_pop').show()}, function(){
    $('.hover_pop').hide();
});
```

You have closed the curly brace of first function at the end previously

**EDITED**

```
$(document).on({
   mouseover: function() {
       $('.hover_pop').show()
   },
   mouseout: function() {
       $('.hover_pop').hide()
   } 
}, '.lister1 img');​
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/coosal/KVA9a/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my stupid mistake :) but unfortunately this still does not work - does not now show the div on hover. I think there could be a conflict somewhere else in my code